# Non-parametric test for station variation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

*Certain disease reduces the concentration of calcium in people's blood. To test the effectiveness of a drug for the treatment of the disease, 9 individuals with the disease underwent an assessment in which 5 of them, selected at random, underwent treatment with the drug, and the remaining 4 served as a control group and underwent treatment. with a placebo. The variation in calcium concentration was measured in mg / 100 mL before and after the evaluation period. Consider a non-parametric test based on the positions of the variation in the concentration of calcium in the blood after the evaluation period, in which the null hypothesis is that the drug is inefficient in treating the disease. The test statistic, WS, is given by the sum of the ranks of the 4 individuals in the control group, and the null hypothesis is rejected when $W_S ≤ 11$. What is the level of significance of the test?*

I think the questioner used the Mann-Whitney test. However, in the literature I am using, I found only an approximation of the normal distribution for the test statistic ($n_i \leq 20$).

My question would be how to compute the significance of this test? Wouldn't it be a rough approximation to use an approximation on a small sample? (The result of the question is 1/63 - I also don't know how the author arrived at the result. I would like to find out)

Comment: For small sample sizes there are tables of the Wilcoxon Signed Rank test, such as found in [this link](http://plantsys.elte.hu/oktatas/Biometria/tablazatok/Wilcoxon_table_ketmintas_probahoz.pdf#:~:text=1%3A%20Table%20of%20Critical%20Values%20for%20the%20Wilcoxon,0%3A05%20%3D%200%3A10%202-tail%20%3D%200%3A05%20%3D%200%3A10).

Comment: For larger sample sizes, a normal approximation is used. Normal means and variances are found using group sample sizes. For one explanation see [this link](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~wild/ChanceEnc/Ch10.wilcoxon.pdf), p 7.